# Why the messages sent via contact form all go to the spam box? What's wrong with my code?

Tags: php, contact-form

I'm using the code below for the messages sent via the contact form of my website. The issue is that all the messages arrive in the spam box. 
I suspect that this is because of this part `"From:" . $_POST['email']`

What are your thoughts on this issue?

Thanks,

```
<?php
// Email Submit
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['message']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

  // detect & prevent header injections
  $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
      exit;
    }
  }

  //send email
 mail( "XYZ****@hotmail.com", "New message from: ".$_POST['name'], $_POST['message']."\nFrom page: ". str_replace("http://", "", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']), "From:" . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . "BCC: ABC****@gmail.com" );

}
?>
```

Comment: You can add an SPF to the DNSrecords, it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Make Your PHP mail() Emails Less Spammy
Use Headers

```
$headers .= "Reply-To: The Sender <sender@sender.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: The Sender <sender@sender.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "From: The Sender <senter@sender.com>\r\n";
```

But headers  are good for more than just setting details about the sender. They are also important for setting the content type, the email priority, and more. Here are how some additional headers look.

```
$headers .= "Organization: Sender Organization\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n"
```

Be sure to replace the fourth parameter with the $headers variable as shown below.

```
mail("recipient@recipient.com", "Message", "A simple message.", $headers);
```